# How do i restrict time to one hour in datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have the following JavaScript code that uses of a `StartDate` & `EndDate` field.

What this code does is to restrict the dates on the `EndDate` field to the day you have chosen in the `StartDate` field.

What I am trying to do is to restrict time as well, for example the "datetimepicker" consists of a drop-down with Hours.

How do I restrict the `EndDate` field to one hour(according to the hour I have chosen from the `StartDate` field plus one) and maybe disable the rest of available hours?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             var dates = $('#StartDate, #EndDate').datetimepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                 hourMin: 9,
                 hourMax: 17,
                 minDate: '1',
                 maxDate: null,
                 controlType: 'select',
                 timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
                 beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                 firstDay: 1,
                 changeFirstDay: false,
                 onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                     var option = this.id == "StartDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                         instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                         date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                             instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                             $.datetimepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                             selectedDate, instance.settings);
                     var edate;
                     var otherOption;
                     var d;                

                     if (option == "minDate") {
                         otherOption = "maxDate";   

                         d = date.getDate() + 0;                               
                     }

                     else if (option == "maxDate") {
                         otherOption = "minDate";   

                         d = date.getDate() - 0;                           
                     }

                     var m = date.getMonth();
                     var y = date.getFullYear();
                     edate = new Date(y, m, d);

                     dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", option, date);
                     dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", otherOption, edate);
                 }
             });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this plugin: 
[DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)
, then you can:

```
$('#rest_example_3').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2010, 11, 20, 8, 30),
    maxDate: new Date(2010, 11, 31, 17, 30)
});
```

Basically you need pass min date and end date with hours

Comment: the one hour restriction it has to be generated dynamically in the EndDate field according to what the user selected in the StartDate field, for example if he has chosen 12:00 to get a choise of up to 13:00 in the EndField

Comment: Noone is replying , no hope :(

Comment: You need to have two datetimepickers. One for each textbox. And onClose of the first, you define the EndDate of the second. You have a very nice example in their examples page. (Restrict a start and end date by using onSelect and onClose events)

Comment: Hi Tiago , i am already using two datetimepickers as you can notice in the begininning of the code. I have done the rest that you say and it works fine with the date but i cannot control and restrict the time at all

Comment: Are you using the timepicker AddOn from the site that i sent you?

Comment: try onClose of the first to set the minDate of the second. Passing the date as new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM).